# cabal: error while loading shared libraries: libHSzlib-0.5.4.1-ghc7.6.3.so

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, centos7

I've done a fresh install of the Haskell platform on CentOS 7, like so:

```
[amy@wombat115 ~]$ sudo yum install haskell-platform
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.sunet.se
 * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * extras: ftp.sunet.se
 * updates: ftp.sunet.se
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package haskell-platform.x86_64 0:2013.2.0.0-36.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ghc-haskell-platform-devel = 2013.2.0.0-36.el7 for package: haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cabal-install = 1.16.0.2 for package: haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cabal-install.x86_64 0:1.16.0.2-32.el7 will be installed
---> Package ghc-haskell-platform-devel.x86_64 0:2013.2.0.0-36.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ghc = 7.6.3 for package: ghc-haskell-platform-devel-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ghc.x86_64 0:7.6.3-18.3.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Arch                    Version                             Repository             Size
=====================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 haskell-platform                            x86_64                  2013.2.0.0-36.el7                   epel                   12 k
Installing for dependencies:
 cabal-install                               x86_64                  1.16.0.2-32.el7                     epel                  452 k
 ghc                                         x86_64                  7.6.3-18.3.el7                      epel                   35 k
 ghc-haskell-platform-devel                  x86_64                  2013.2.0.0-36.el7                   epel                   15 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 514 k
Installed size: 2.9 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/4): haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                          |  12 kB  00:00:00     
(2/4): ghc-haskell-platform-devel-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                |  15 kB  00:00:00     
(3/4): ghc-7.6.3-18.3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                          |  35 kB  00:00:00     
(4/4): cabal-install-1.16.0.2-32.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                               | 452 kB  00:00:01     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                461 kB/s | 514 kB  00:00:01     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : ghc-7.6.3-18.3.el7.x86_64                                                                                         1/4 
  Installing : ghc-haskell-platform-devel-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64                                                               2/4 
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.5ERaqJ: line 1: /usr/bin/ghc-pkg: No such file or directory
  Installing : cabal-install-1.16.0.2-32.el7.x86_64                                                                              3/4 
  Installing : haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64                                                                         4/4 
  Verifying  : cabal-install-1.16.0.2-32.el7.x86_64                                                                              1/4 
  Verifying  : ghc-haskell-platform-devel-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64                                                               2/4 
  Verifying  : ghc-7.6.3-18.3.el7.x86_64                                                                                         3/4 
  Verifying  : haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0-36.el7.x86_64                                                                         4/4 

Installed:
  haskell-platform.x86_64 0:2013.2.0.0-36.el7                                                                                        

Dependency Installed:
  cabal-install.x86_64 0:1.16.0.2-32.el7    ghc.x86_64 0:7.6.3-18.3.el7    ghc-haskell-platform-devel.x86_64 0:2013.2.0.0-36.el7   

Complete!
```

But I get the following error:

```
[amy@wombat115 ~]$ cabal update
cabal: error while loading shared libraries: libHSzlib-0.5.4.1-ghc7.6.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the following, to no effect:

```
sudo yum reinstall ghc-zlib-devel
sudo yum reinstall zlib-devel
sudo yum reinstall ghc-ghc-devel
```

---

EDIT: I have also tried the following:

```
sudo yum reinstall ghc-zlib-devel-0.5.4.1
sudo yum reinstall ghc-zlib-devel-0.5.4.1-26.el7
sudo yum reinstall cabal-install
sudo yum reinstall ghc-Cabal
```

---

EDIT: If `yum whatprovides libHSzlib*ghc*` is to be believed, `ghc-zlib-devel` installs `libHSzlib-0.5.4.1-ghc7.6.3.so`. However, the only file `find / -name 'libHSzlib*.so' returns is`libHSzlib-0.5.4.1-ghc7.8.3.so` (note the *8* vs. *6*).

Comment: How about `yum install ghc-zlib-devel-0.5.3.1`?  It appears centos has a broken packaging and fails to install their build of the haskell zlib bindings.  FYI, I haven't tested this but just ran a quick `yum whatprovides */libHSzlib*`

Comment: I tried `yum install ghc-zlib-devel-0.5.4.1` (I assume you meant 0.5.*4*.1), but no change.

Comment: Please see additional edits to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

First, I installed ghc manually.

```
wget https://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.8.4/ghc-7.8.4-i386-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.xz
tar xvf ghc-7.8.4-i386-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.xz 
cd ghc-7.8.4
sudo mkdir /usr/local/ghc-7.8.4
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ghc-7.8.4
```

**NOTE:** Even though the version I installed was made on a Debian 7 "wheezey" system and supposedly only requires `libgmp.so.10`, I got error messages about `libgmp.so.3`. I worked around that by doing the following, which I know is a **bad thing to do**:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10 /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3
```

Next, I *tried* installing the Haskell Platform manually, using the command:

```
./platform.sh /home/amy/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.xz
```

but I got the now familiar error messages about `libHSzlib-0.5.4.1-ghc7.6.3.so`.

So I manually installed cabal.

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/cabal.git
cd cabal/Cabal
ghc -threaded --make Setup
./Setup configure
./Setup build
sudo ./Setup install
cd ../cabal-install
./bootstrap.sh
```